# Ajax response succeeds, but cannot use data (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, eval

I am trying to retrieve data from a web service using an ajax call. The call is succeeding, because I am able to successfully print the data in the console using console.log().  However when I attempt to take my data, and convert from a string into an array, the code fails.  I am currently trying to use eval, but have also tried to use JSON.parse. Both fail with an error of **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**.  Any ideas on how to get around this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: (redacted)
    data: (redacted)
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.d);
        var data =  eval("[" + response.d + "]");
```

This is where my code fails.  Like I said, console.log(response.d) works, with an output simlilar to this: { 'code':'1234', 'description':'Record 1'}, { 'code':'1234', 'description':'Record 2'}, { 'code':'1234', 'description':'Record 3'}

Is my problem the use of eval? Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think the sample result you've given here reproduces the issue. Any chance your results has apostrophes or quotes that break the quotes on your keys or values?

Comment: The sample response you gave us shows an example of invalid json.

Comment: Is your server response really a JSON literal with a `d` property that does contain a JS object literal?

Comment: Where is this magical `d` property coming from that so many of these questions are referencing? we need to fix that documentation wherever it is.

Comment: How are you creating this JSON?  are you sure `response.d` is a string?  If it is, that means whoever made the JSON response is incorrect.  You should *not* be sending JSON inside JSON (do not double encode).

Comment: NOTE: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` is the content type of the *request*, not the *response*! Are you sending a JSON string to the server? If not, remove this line.

Comment: apsillers - that was it, Thank you. Will also look into the mysterious d property.

Comment: What *exactly* does `console.log(response)` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use `JSON.parse()` here instead of `eval` for decoding JSON strings.

However in this case I believe the return data has already been decoded by jQuery. `console.log(response.d)` returns a nice looking object and not a "{...}...." string correct?

Comment: Thanks for the info, will look into JSON.parse(). Turns out I was returning a string, but it had some random apostrophe's in the data which corrupted the string. Thanks though